# Wordpress Content not retrieving on .load jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to get posts from a wordpress query_posts external php file via `.load` jQuery function.

I'm getting the correct html code, but the wordpress loop part of the code is not loading.

My code is:

HTML:

```
<article class="delivery-individual">
        <!-- # CONTENT HERE -->
</article>
```

jQuery:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delivery-individual").load("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/temakis.php",
    function() {window.alert('Load was performed.');});
    });
    </script>
```

External file:

```
<h3>Temakis</h3>

<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'temakis');
query_posts($args);
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>

<div class="item-individual">
  <img src="<?php the_field("imagem-produto");?>" width="150" height="150" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?> "/>
  <div class="item-individual-info">
  <h4><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h4>
  <p class="descricao-delivery"><? echo get_post_field('post_content'); ?></p>
  <p class="valor-delivery">R$ <? the_field("preco"); ?></p>
  </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The request is ok, because I'm getting the h3 correctly.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to set this as a template file, so you can test it to make sure the loop itself works? Take a look at this link, your loop may be incorrectly made: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: Also just as a note, that in general, it's bad practice to use <?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?> inside of your Javascript :). This can lead to issues down the road and is better to just load the absolute path or use JS to generate that (using window.location or something, depending on the URI).

Comment: Hey friend, i tested the loop outside the function and works great!

Comment: Do you have any ideia whats is wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

place your temakis.php file inside the root folder & load this one,

```
"<?php home_url(); ?>/temakis.php"
```

Comment: "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/temakis.php"

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.get("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/temakis.php", function(data){
      $(".delivery-individual").html(data);
   });
});
</script>
```